# MSDataShape Provider Porting to XML (SQL Data Shaping)

Tags: sql, vba, vb6, ado

I have a legacy VB6 application that extensively uses SHAPE(ed) queries. One such query is:

```
SHAPE  
{ 
SELECT 
[PRYL COMM Record ID],
[PRYL COMM AR SALE Document #],
[PRYL COMM Dated] Dated,
[AR SALE Ext Document #] [AR Doc],
[PRYL COMM Customer Name] [Customer Name],
[PRYL COMM Salesperson] [Salesperson],
[PRYL COMM Salesperson Number] [Sls Num],
[PRYL COMM Salesperson Percent] [Percent],
[PRYL COMM Location] [Location],
[PRYL COMM Price] Price,
[PRYL COMM Cost] Cost,
[PRYL COMM Profit] Profit,
[PRYL COMM Margin] Margin,
[PRYL COMM Calc Cost] [Calc Cost],
[PRYL COMM Calc Profit] [Calc Profit],
[PRYL COMM Calc Margin] [Calc Margin],
[PRYL COMM Comm Amount] [Comm Amount],
[PRYL COMM ESP Amount] [Fixed $],
[PRYL COMM Spiff Amount] [Spiff $],
[PRYL COMM Delete] [Delete] 
FROM [Pyrl - Commission],[AR Sales]  
And [PRYL COMM AR SALE Document #] = [AR SALE Document #] 
AND [PRYL COMM Salesperson] = 'Trevor Janok' 
AND [PRYL COMM Payroll ID] = '62'
} 
AS ParentCMD 
APPEND 
(
{
SELECT 
[PRYL COMMD Record ID],
[PRYL COMMD Header ID],
[PRYL COMMD AR SALED ID],
[PRYL COMMD Pay YN] [Pay YN],
[PRYL COMMD Qty] [Qty],
[PRYL COMMD Model Number] [Model Number],
[PRYL COMMD Serial Number] [Serial Number],
[PRYL COMMD Unit Price] [Price],
[PRYL COMMD Unit Cost] [Cost],
[PRYL COMMD Profit] [Profit],
[PRYL COMMD Calc Cost] [Calc Cost],
[PRYL COMMD Calc Profit] [Calc Profit],
[PRYL COMMD Calc Margin] [Calc Margin],
[PRYL COMMD Comm Amount] [Comm Amount],
[PRYL COMMD Comm Percent] [Comm %],
[PRYL COMMD ESP Amount] [Fixed $],
[PRYL COMMD Spiff Amount] [Spiff $],
PRYLCOMMDExpInvCost [Exp Inv],
[PRYL COMMD Notes] [Notes],
[PRYL COMMD Costed By] [Cost by]  
FROM [Pyrl - Commission Detail] 
}
AS ChildCMD 
Relate [PRYL COMM Record ID] To [PRYL COMMD Header ID]
)
as ChildCMD
```

This feeds into an ADO recordset, which I then point a MSHFlexGrid control to this recordset.
The control displays the child records. Like so:

[image]

(This is a custom control based on-top of MSHFlexGrid)

This works great, however Microsoft has long stated the MSDataShape provider will be deprecated. However, I think it's been almost a decade since that notice was posted.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-data-shaping-service-for-ole-db-ado-service-provider?view=sql-server-2017

Regardless, I really want to port this code over to something else to avoid this becoming a disaster, and not having to force my users on a specific Windows version.

It's been mentioned to port the query to "XML". I'm aware of the "FOR XML" Statement. However, does anyone have any examples on how to properly convert the above query into an XML equivalent and feed into a Recordset the MSHFlexGrid control will understand?

I'm also unfamiliar of how to produce my own nested Recordset object. If I could build that manually - I also assume that could get me where I need to go.

I have manually created the MSHFlexGrid rows/child rows, and populated the data with simple queries. But I also lose all data binding functionality with this method..

I can also save the recordset to XML via ADO. This gives me the schema, and the data from the Shape query. But I assume this is useless, as I need to re-run the query with new parameters each time.

```
<xml xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
    xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
    xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
    xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
<s:Schema id='RowsetSchema'>
    <s:ElementType name='row' content='eltOnly' rs:CommandTimeout='1200' rs:updatable='true' rs:ReshapeName='ParentCMD'>
        <s:AttributeType name='c0' rs:name='PRYL COMM Record ID' rs:number='1' rs:basecatalog='Freds' rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission'
             rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMM Record ID' rs:keycolumn='true' rs:autoincrement='true'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='i8' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='19' rs:fixedlength='true' rs:maybenull='false'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='c1' rs:name='PRYL COMM AR SALE Document #' rs:number='2' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true'
             rs:basecatalog='Freds' rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMM AR SALE Document #'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='i8' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='19' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='Dated' rs:number='3' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='Freds'
             rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMM Dated'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='dateTime' rs:dbtype='timestamp' dt:maxLength='16' rs:scale='3' rs:precision='23' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='c3' rs:name='AR Doc' rs:number='4' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='Freds'
             rs:basetable='AR Sales' rs:basecolumn='AR SALE Ext Document #'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='50'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='c4' rs:name='Customer Name' rs:number='5' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true'
             rs:basecatalog='Freds' rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMM Customer Name'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='150'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='Salesperson' rs:number='6' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='Freds'
             rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMM Salesperson'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='25'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='c6' rs:name='Sls Num' rs:number='7' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='Freds'
             rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMM Salesperson Number'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='10'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='Percent' rs:number='8' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='Freds'
             rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMM Salesperson Percent'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='int' dt:maxLength='4' rs:precision='10' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='Location' rs:number='9' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='Freds'
             rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMM Location'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='5'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='Price' rs:number='10' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='Freds'
             rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMM Price'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='number' rs:dbtype='currency' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='19' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='Cost' rs:number='11' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='Freds'
             rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMM Cost'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='number' rs:dbtype='currency' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='19' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='Profit' rs:number='12' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='Freds'
             rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMM Profit'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='number' rs:dbtype='currency' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='19' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='Margin' rs:number='13' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='Freds'
             rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMM Margin'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='float' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='15' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='c13' rs:name='Calc Cost' rs:number='14' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='Freds'
             rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMM Calc Cost'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='number' rs:dbtype='currency' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='19' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='c14' rs:name='Calc Profit' rs:number='15' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true'
             rs:basecatalog='Freds' rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMM Calc Profit'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='number' rs:dbtype='currency' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='19' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='c15' rs:name='Calc Margin' rs:number='16' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true'
             rs:basecatalog='Freds' rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMM Calc Margin'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='float' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='15' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='c16' rs:name='Comm Amount' rs:number='17' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true'
             rs:basecatalog='Freds' rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMM Comm Amount'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='number' rs:dbtype='currency' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='19' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='c17' rs:name='Fixed $' rs:number='18' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='Freds'
             rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMM ESP Amount'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='number' rs:dbtype='currency' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='19' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='c18' rs:name='Spiff $' rs:number='19' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='Freds'
             rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMM Spiff Amount'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='number' rs:dbtype='currency' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='19' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='Delete' rs:number='20' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='Freds'
             rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMM Delete'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='10'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:ElementType name='ChildCMD' content='eltOnly' rs:CommandTimeout='1200' rs:updatable='true' rs:ReshapeName='ChildCMD'
         rs:relation='010000000200000000000000'>
            <s:AttributeType name='c0' rs:name='PRYL COMMD Record ID' rs:number='1' rs:basecatalog='Freds' rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission Detail'
                 rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMMD Record ID' rs:keycolumn='true' rs:autoincrement='true'>
                <s:datatype dt:type='i8' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='19' rs:fixedlength='true' rs:maybenull='false'/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name='c1' rs:name='PRYL COMMD Header ID' rs:number='2' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true'
                 rs:basecatalog='Freds' rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission Detail' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMMD Header ID'>
                <s:datatype dt:type='i8' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='19' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name='c2' rs:name='PRYL COMMD AR SALED ID' rs:number='3' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true'
                 rs:basecatalog='Freds' rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission Detail' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMMD AR SALED ID'>
                <s:datatype dt:type='i8' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='19' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name='c3' rs:name='Pay YN' rs:number='4' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='Freds'
                 rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission Detail' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMMD Pay YN'>
                <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='10' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name='Qty' rs:number='5' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='Freds'
                 rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission Detail' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMMD Qty'>
                <s:datatype dt:type='int' dt:maxLength='4' rs:precision='10' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name='c5' rs:name='Model Number' rs:number='6' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true'
                 rs:basecatalog='Freds' rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission Detail' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMMD Model Number'>
                <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='40'/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name='c6' rs:name='Serial Number' rs:number='7' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true'
                 rs:basecatalog='Freds' rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission Detail' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMMD Serial Number'>
                <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='40'/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name='Price' rs:number='8' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='Freds'
                 rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission Detail' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMMD Unit Price'>
                <s:datatype dt:type='number' rs:dbtype='currency' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='19' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name='Cost' rs:number='9' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='Freds'
                 rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission Detail' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMMD Unit Cost'>
                <s:datatype dt:type='number' rs:dbtype='currency' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='19' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name='Profit' rs:number='10' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='Freds'
                 rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission Detail' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMMD Profit'>
                <s:datatype dt:type='number' rs:dbtype='currency' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='19' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name='c10' rs:name='Calc Cost' rs:number='11' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='Freds'
                 rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission Detail' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMMD Calc Cost'>
                <s:datatype dt:type='number' rs:dbtype='currency' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='19' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name='c11' rs:name='Calc Profit' rs:number='12' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true'
                 rs:basecatalog='Freds' rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission Detail' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMMD Calc Profit'>
                <s:datatype dt:type='number' rs:dbtype='currency' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='19' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name='c12' rs:name='Calc Margin' rs:number='13' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true'
                 rs:basecatalog='Freds' rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission Detail' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMMD Calc Margin'>
                <s:datatype dt:type='float' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='15' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name='c13' rs:name='Comm Amount' rs:number='14' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true'
                 rs:basecatalog='Freds' rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission Detail' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMMD Comm Amount'>
                <s:datatype dt:type='number' rs:dbtype='currency' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='19' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name='c14' rs:name='Comm %' rs:number='15' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='Freds'
                 rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission Detail' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMMD Comm Percent'>
                <s:datatype dt:type='float' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='15' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name='c15' rs:name='Fixed $' rs:number='16' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='Freds'
                 rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission Detail' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMMD ESP Amount'>
                <s:datatype dt:type='number' rs:dbtype='currency' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='19' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name='c16' rs:name='Spiff $' rs:number='17' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='Freds'
                 rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission Detail' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMMD Spiff Amount'>
                <s:datatype dt:type='number' rs:dbtype='currency' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='19' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name='c17' rs:name='Exp Inv' rs:number='18' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='Freds'
                 rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission Detail' rs:basecolumn='PRYLCOMMDExpInvCost'>
                <s:datatype dt:type='number' rs:dbtype='currency' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='19' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name='Notes' rs:number='19' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='Freds'
                 rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission Detail' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMMD Notes'>
                <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='1073741823' rs:long='true'/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name='c19' rs:name='Cost by' rs:number='20' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='Freds'
                 rs:basetable='Pyrl - Commission Detail' rs:basecolumn='PRYL COMMD Costed By'>
                <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='50'/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:extends type='rs:rowbase'/>
        </s:ElementType>
        <s:AttributeType name='c21' rs:name='AR SALE Document #' rs:number='22' rs:basecatalog='Freds' rs:basetable='AR Sales'
             rs:basecolumn='AR SALE Document #' rs:keycolumn='true' rs:hidden='true' rs:autoincrement='true'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='int' dt:maxLength='4' rs:precision='10' rs:fixedlength='true' rs:maybenull='false'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:extends type='rs:rowbase'/>
    </s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
</xml>
```

Comment: If you need to stick with the MSHFlexGrid control this will be challenging.  The MSHFlexGrid control requires a field type of `adChapter` for fields that contain nested RecordSet's.  However, you cannot manually create a RecordSet with this field type.  I only know of 2 ways to create a RecordSet with this field type and both those ways are deprecated:  the DataShape provider and the Simple provider.

Comment: @BrianMStafford That's unfortunate! But great info, had no idea about the `adChapter` field type. I might just have to rethink my UI and forget the MSHFlexGrid.